# Lattice Sieving

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, sieve-theory

What are some good references for Lattice Sieving in Number Field Sieve? Could someone suggest some research papers in this area?(Theoretical and Computational Perspective)

Comment: Related post by the same OP on math.SE: [Number field sieve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2223519).

Answer (score 1):

The References section in [Readme](https://sourceforge.net/p/msieve/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Readme) from the excellent [msieve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/) integer factorization software states:

> Franke and Kleinjung's 'Continued Fractions and Lattice Sieving' is
>   the only modern reference available on techniques used in a high-
>   performance lattice siever.

Comment: Paper currently available at http://www.hyperelliptic.org/tanja/SHARCS/talks/FrankeKleinjung.pdf